# Form matrix A (Ax=b) with submatrices to solve linear system?

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra

I want to use the Cholesky method for Ax=b. My A matrix is a 5 diagonal matrix, which has equations of submatrices of the form '3*I + B' in the diagonals. B is one submatrix in another variable and I is the unit matrix. I want to put this equation from submatrices in the A matrix, like:

```
A=[[3*I + B, 0, 0 ,0],[0, 3*I + B , 0, 0],[0, 0, 3*I + B, 0],[0, 0, 0,3*I + B]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear if you want help performing the factorization or just  how to create block matrices.

If it's block matrices you can use numpy, for example to create:

1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1

(Upper row is the identity matrix and then zeros matrix, and lower row is zeros and then identity).

`np.block([[np.eye(3),np.zeros((3,3))],[np.zeros((3,3)), np.eye(3)]])`

If you just want to perform cholesky factorization - you can just use np.linalg.cholesky